# Why do I encounter this problem in python while loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem with my code and I think it's because of my while loop. Can someone help me with it? Sorry if comments are complicated to understand (I added comments in my native language first).

Edit 1: I forget to change taxes variable to kambiyo_yuzde, so it should have been look like this:

The problem is, the while loop doesn't end at value i want to get. For example, when i entered "usd_bolu_tl" "7.500" and "sahip_tl" "2000", value of satis_tl should be 266,6*7.000 which is 1866.2, and value of deger_tl  should be 2004. What i want to calculate with my while loop is that it should add 0.001 value to the "yeni_usd" variable every time it loops and end when satis_tl's value (which is 266.6*7.000+0.001) is bigger than deger_tl (which is 2004)

```
kambiyo_yuzde = 2 / 1000
usd_bolu_tl = input("current rate: ")

sahip_tl = input("how much money you have in turkish liras: ")
# money plus taxes
deger_tl = float(sahip_tl) + (float(sahip_tl) * float(kambiyo_yuzde))

print("Bu tl değerinde dolar alabilmek için kambiyo vergisi ile beraber ", deger_tl, "tl ödemeniz gerekir.")

# usd we bought with turkish liras
alinacak_usd = float(sahip_tl) / float(usd_bolu_tl)

# new currency
yeni_usd = 7.000
# selling
satis_tl = float(alinacak_usd) * float(yeni_usd)

while satis_tl < deger_tl:
    print("yeni dolarin degeri: ", yeni_usd)
    yeni_usd += 0.001

# to profit
print("minimum kar icin dolarinizi satmaniz gereken deger: ", yeni_usd, "'dir.")

input("cikis yapmak icin herhangi bir tusa basiniz.")
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: You are using kambiyo_yuzde before assigning any value to it

Comment: Since you have a condition already for the while loop, I bet you don't need that break statement, even because it would be inside some if-statement body if that was correct ;)

Comment: your loop will run exactly once (if condition is true to begin with) due to `break`. If that is a choice, why use `while` at all? (Also the loop has no update statement; an update statement would modifiy either `satis_tl` or `deger_tl` within the loop).

Comment: You. need to recalculate `satis_tl = float(alinacak_usd) * float(yeni_usd)` inside the loop if you want the loop to break naturally. Also remove `break` from the while loop

Answer (score 1):

The [break](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) statement inside the while loop will terminate the execution of the loop after the first iteration, so you'd need to reconsider to remove that `break` at all or reconsider the initial condition to stop your while loop.

Additionally, as per the section of your code shared I don't see that you have initialized any values for the `kambiyo_yuzde` variable.

Comment: `usd_bolu_tl = input("current rate: ")` initializes the variable!

Comment: Good catch! I missed that part! Let me edit the answer.

Comment: The thing is OP hasn't mentioned his problem!

Comment: Thank you, i removed break code and edited my question to explain my question better.